# Python: Can print answer but cannot return answer (Palindrome Partitioning)

Tags: python

In the Python code below, when I input `s = "ab"`, I get `[[]]` which I should get `[["a","b"]]`. I have checked the two functions individually and they turned out to be right. I can even print out the answer `[["a","b"]]` in line 26, but I cannot get the answer from return. I am quite confused here and I appreciate any ideas that can help.

```
class Solution:
    # @param s, a string
    # @return a list of lists of string
    def partition(self, s):
        ############### Depth First Search: Usually we will use RECURSION a!!!
        if s == "":
            return [[]]
        if len(s) == 1:
            return [[s[0]]]
        self.result = []
        temp = []
        stack = [] # stack is a 2D lists
        for k in range(len(s)):
            stack.append([])
        for i in range(len(s)):
            for j in range(i+1,len(s)+1):
                substr = s[i:j]
                if substr == substr[::-1]:
                    stack[i].append(s[i:j])
        self.dfs(temp, stack, 0, len(s))
        return self.result

    def dfs(self, temp, stack, start, end):
        if start == end:
            self.result.append(temp)
            print(self.result)
            return
        else:
            for i in range(len(stack[start])):
                temp.append(stack[start][i])
                self.dfs(temp, stack, start+len(stack[start][i]), end)
                temp.pop()
```

Comment: I think in the function dfs(), self.result.append(temp) get the [["a","b"]] within the object, so when I return self.result in partition(), it should be [["a","b"]], but it actually get [[]]. Is there anything wrong here?

Comment: @frostnational: `self.result` *is* set, and that is what `partition()` returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sharing `temp` between recursive calls:

```
temp.append(stack[start][i])
self.dfs(temp, stack, start+len(stack[start][i]), end)
temp.pop()
```

The list object referenced by `temp` is appended to `self.result`:

```
if start == end:
    self.result.append(temp)
```

but you then **empty** that shared list object again by popping after returning. This removes the elements from the shared list object *after* you printed.

You want to append a *copy* instead:

```
if start == end:
    self.result.append(temp[:])
```

You don't really **need** `temp`. Just build new lists instead:

```
for item in stack[start]:
    self.dfs([item], stack, start + len(item), end)
```

You never do more than add one item to `temp`, then remove it again; starting from an empty `temp` list that means you can just as well build new list objects for the recursive calls.

Instead of looping over a `range()` then indexing, just loop over `stack[start]` *directly*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though I need sometime to understand it. I think for the last recursive call, it is dfs(["a","b"], stack, 2, 2) so when it runs, self.result.append(temp) should always make the self.result [["a","b"]], isn't it? And when I print self.result, it got right. Why is it not right in function partition?

Comment: @jasonccc: then your function returns, and `temp` *still refers to the same nested list object*.

Comment: Thanks for adding comments. I understand it now. I need the index i because in 'start+len(stack[start][i]' there is an i, but the point you said is very meaningful!

Comment: @jasonccc: sorry, forgot one reference. `stack[start][i]` is replaced by `item`.